# Xtext: Arithmetic example: What uses the calculator class and how?

Tags: eclipse, xtext

Ive been looking at the Arithmetics example that comes with xtext and I stumbled upon the Calculator.java class under the org.eclipse.xtext.example.arithmetics.interpreter package but I cannot find any reference to it.

I understand that this class is used to walk the AST and evaluate the expressions but who is calling it and how is it registered?

I have a similar example which I am setting up from scratch and using the arithmetics as an example, however I dont know how to register the AST walker so that each time a tree is visited the particular method is triggered as in the Calculator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the `Calculator` class (either directly within the Java Editor or in the Package Explorer) and select *References -> Workspace* you will get listed all occurrences of the `Calculator` type. You'll see that it is used in the `ArthimeticsValidator` and `InterpreterAutoEdit` types, where the latter is responsible for actually evaluating an expression within its `evaluate` method. From the `InterpreterAutoEdit` class, you can work your way up and see that it is registered via the `ArthimeticsUiModule`.